# HTML several elements different scrolling

Tags: html

I have 3 html elements. All elements overlay each other. They should be scrollable:

- The first element should be scrollable in x direction and be fixed in y direction.
- The second element should be scrollable in y direction and be fixed in x direction.
- The third element should be scrollable in x direction and in y direction.

All components should use the same scrollbar -> i want one vertical scrollbar and one horizontal scrollbar

I'm using react, but I think that fact doesn't have any influence to this question.

Is that possible in html/css? How can I specify the scroll behavior of child elements?

Comment: You can make each one scrollable, but it sounds like a horrible user experience (overlapping scrollable areas), what exactly are you trying to achieve? There may be a better approach.

Comment: I wanted to create a view like a chart with fixed y axis in x direction, fixed x axis in y direction and scrollable content. But I solved it in another way now. Thanks